# Custom Domain issue for Application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I designed one Web Application(MOOC) on Google Course Builder and want a custom domain for this application.

I performed all the steps exactly mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl).

After this the settings of my application shows I have successfully mapped custom domain for my application. But still when I put my application URL with custom domain the browser shows the error that "The site can't be reached".

Comment: Are you accessing the naked domain (aka example.com rather than www.example.com)?

Comment: There can be many reasons for a `site can't be reached` error, not necessarily caused by your app: https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=the%20site%20cannot%20be%20reached. So you need to debug this further: find out if the custom domain is properly mapped to your app(DNS lookups), find out if requests are reaching your app and if it's working properly (check app's status and request logs on the console, maybe also check the app's functionality on `appspot.com` instead of the custom domain), try using some other browser/OS, etc.

Comment: Hello Dan Sir, I checked all the DNS Lookups & it shows all the records(A,AAAA) except CNAME record missing to my Custom Domain. One more thing is how to check the request from my custom domain is reach to my app?I checked Apps log from console but its not understandable to me. So is there any way to synthesize this.?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause, assuming you followed all the directions accurately, is that the DNS changes have not yet propagated. Give it some time.

If it has been longer than 24 hours, then you should verify each of the following:

1. Check your Domain Registrar's records to verify that the name servers associated with your domain are the ones that you updated. You can use an [online Whois](https://www.whois.net/) tool to look up this information. Make sure those are the actual name servers that you updated. If not edit your domain registry entry to point to your intended name servers.
2. If the previous step shows the correct name servers listed, then examine your domain's current records with an nslookup tool. [Here is a web-based one](http://network-tools.com/nslook/). Put in your domain name and query all the records. Verify that your records are there.

Comment: No,I did it before 1 week ago & it requires only 24 hours to propagate the DNS changes. So,rather than DNS changes propagation, what will be possible causes the issue I faced?

Comment: Updated answer with more troubleshooting information.

Comment: Hello Brett Sir, Thank You very much for replying me...But I don't understand the meaning of "Name server updation" & also not known how to update it. Also not remembered I did this kind of step while custom-domain mapping to my application. As per your mentioned steps I found my Domain's Name Servers but not remembered whether I updated it or not. If not,can u tell me the steps for it? Also tell me how to edit "Domain registry entry". Just want to mention my Domain status is: Ragitrar-Lock.So will be this matters for my changes?& Extremely sorry for this trouble.